# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.temp' doesn't exist, query was: SHOW CREATE TABLE temp

Tags: magento2.3

Magento 2.3.* files upgraded using composer. After that used to upgrade module setup using following commands but facing error.

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Error:

```
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
/generated/code/Composer
/generated/code/MSP
/generated/code/Magento
/generated/code/Symfony

The directory '/generated/metadata/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.temp' doesn't exist, query was: SHOW CREATE TABLE temp
```

Help is much appreciated..I have tried many times facing issues, is there any permission issue? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with your phpmyadmin database - magento.. temp table not exists in database.. if you can create than facing issue like table or view exists than go to `/var/lib/mysql/`  here find database folder name remove folder or remove `temp.frm`

I hope its work for you.